# Fail to interact with smart contract as owner

Tags: .net, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nethereum

I'm trying to interact with a smart contract ([Solidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidity)) as an owner. I tried first to do it through Nethereum in code, but I kept receiving the ownership error message I set in the owner modifier.

I tried then to interact with the contract through myetherwallet with the contract address and [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), but I was still getting the same result.

I created four different functions to test it, and I will show it in code. The first uses the modifier, the second in function require code, the third is an *if* and *else* statement, and the fourth is open to all to see that the contract does react properly.

I also added a return ownerAddress() to see the contract owner is the same as my account. How can I fix this?

The results of the functions:

```
GetNumOne - return the error in the image.
GetNumTwo - return the error in the image.
GetNumThree - return 2.
GetNumFour - return 2 (working well).
GetAdmin - return the address of my account (the one i use to call the contract)

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.5.0  <0.9.0;

contract AdminIssue {
    address Owner;

    constructor()
    {
        Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier OnlyAdmin {
        require(msg.sender == Owner, "Fail! only owner can access this function!");
        _;
    }

    function GetNumOne() public view OnlyAdmin returns(uint)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    function GetNumTwo() public view returns (uint)
    {
       require(msg.sender == Owner, "Fail! only owner can access this function!");
       return 1;
    }

    function GetNumThree() public view  returns (uint)
    {
        if(msg.sender == Owner)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }

    function GetNumFour() public pure returns(uint)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    function GetAdmin() public view returns (address)
    {
        return Owner;
    }
}

class Test
{
    private string contractAbi = "[{ \"inputs\": [], \"stateMutability\": \"nonpayable\",\"type\": \"constructor\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetAdmin\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"address\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"address\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumFour\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"pure\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumOne\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumThree\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumTwo\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" }]";
    private string contractAddress = "0x1cc5e67dab1c3844be03827433f3fa7129466853";

    public async Task<int> CallContract()
    {
        try
        {
            Account _account = new Account(AccountDetails._key, Chain.Rinkeby);
            Web3 _web3 = new Web3(_account, AccountDetails._url);
            Contract _contract = _web3.Eth.GetContract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
            Function _function = _contract.GetFunction("GetNumOne");

            var _result = await _function.CallAsync<int>();
            MessageBox.Show($"result: {_result}");
            return _result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"fail to call contract: {e}");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKrDw.jpg)

Comment: The smart contract seems to work in Remix.ethereum.org, except for the `strong text` text on line 3, but I'm assuming that's just a formatting error on here.

Are you sure you're using the same address in your .net and deployment script?

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "from" parameter in the function call. If you don't add it then the contract sees your address as "0x00000000000000". It seems like a wallet like myetherwallet cannot call owner-only functions.

I'm adding the correct code.

```
class Test
{
    private string contractAbi = "[{ \"inputs\": [], \"stateMutability\": \"nonpayable\",\"type\": \"constructor\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetAdmin\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"address\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"address\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumFour\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"pure\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumOne\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumThree\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" },{ \"inputs\": [], \"name\": \"GetNumTwo\",\"outputs\": [ { \"internalType\": \"uint256\",\"name\": \"\",\"type\": \"uint256\" }],\"stateMutability\": \"view\",\"type\": \"function\" }]";
    private string contractAddress = "0x1cc5e67dab1c3844be03827433f3fa7129466853";

    public async Task<int> CallContract()
    {
        try
        {

        Account _account = new Account(AccountDetails._key, Chain.Rinkeby);
        Web3 _web3 = new Web3(_account, AccountDetails._url);
        Contract _contract = _web3.Eth.GetContract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
        Function _function = _contract.GetFunction("GetNumOne");

        object[] _input = new object[0]; // function receive no parameters
        var _result = 
        await _function.CallAsync<int>("<publicAddress>", null, null, _input);
        
        MessageBox.Show($"result: {_result}");
            return _result;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"fail to call contract: {e}");
            return -1;
        }
    }
```